# Does the Gauss sum attached to $\chi$ ever belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\chi)$?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, characters

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character of conductor $p$. We let $$g(\chi)=\sum_{a=1}^{p}{\chi(a)e^{2i\pi a/p}}$$ be the Gauss sum attached to $\chi$. Is this known that $g(\chi)$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\chi)$, the algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the values of $\chi$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a quadratic Gauss sum for instance.

Comment: If $\chi$ is the quadratic character, then the Gauss sum has degree two over the rationals.

Comment: absolutely, so is there a general statement saying that it does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\chi)$ for any $\chi$?

Comment: I've slightly edited the title; when reading it I have understood the question as asking for something trivially false.

Comment: Ok sorry, thank you very much!

Comment: From a very naive point of view, shouldn't the considered Gauss sum belong to the compositum of $\mathbb{Q}(\chi)$ and some cyclotomic field?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN $\mathbb Q(\chi)$ is itself a cyclotomic field, since $\chi$ has takes values in roots of unity. What you probably imply is that the Gauss sum belongs to $\mathbb Q(\chi,e^{2\pi i/p})$, which is true and obvious. The question is whether it belongs to some particular smaller field.

Comment: there is an element of Galois group fixing ${\mathbb Q}(\chi)$ and sending $e^{2\pi i/p}$ to $e^{2\pi i b/p}$ (here $b$ is a number relatively prime with $p$). Applying this element to $g(\chi)$ we get $\chi(b^{-1})g(\chi)$. Thus $g(\chi) \not \in {\mathbb Q}(\chi)$ if $\chi$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @VictorOstrik, do you want to write a full answer? So that I can validate it